# Prevent specific roles from changing specific tags on aws resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-iam, policy

I am preventing users from doing certain actions on aws resources based on certain tags. But they assume certain roles and change those tags and then perform the forbidden actions. How do I disallow those roles to not be able to change those tags? tag:UntagResources comes to mind but that’s too broad. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tag-policies-prereqs.html

> To remove a tag. You also need service-specific permissions to remove tags. For example, to untag resources in Amazon EC2, you need permissions for ec2:DeleteTags

So that might be a good way to add this limitation on resources of a specific service